# FormData Ajax Request with File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to upload an array of files to a `MVC` Controller, but have not succeeded so far, as the `HttpPostedFileBase[]` turns out `null` on the controller response method.

First, I save multiple uploaded files into a variable like this:

```
$("#file").change(function () {
    fileArray[fileId] = this.files[0];
    fileId++;
});
```

The appending of files to the array works good (checked with Chrome Debugger).

Later, when the user submits the images, I'm appending the data into a FormData object:

```
var data = new FormData();

$.each(fileArray, function (key, value) {
    data.append('files[]', value);
});
```

Then I finally make the `AJAX` Call:

```
    var serviceURL = '@Url.Action("OpenMaterialRequestSubmit", "OpenMaterialRequest")';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: successFunc,
        error: errorFunc
    });
```

To be received by my controller method, with the following header:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> OpenMaterialRequestSubmit(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
```

`files`, as I already said, is always `null`.

Request Payload on Google Chrome Debugger:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryniIQHyAUAYUfecDX
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="Screen Shot 2015-12-03 at 9.19.02 AM.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryniIQHyAUAYUfecDX--
```

Any clue?

Comment: `content-type` should be `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the property name `files[]` to `files`

```
$.each(fileArray, function (key, value) {
    data.append('files', value);
});
```

Side note: An alternative would be to directly add the files to the `FormData` object in the `.change` event

```
var data = new FormData();
$("#file").change(function () {
    data.append('files', $(this).get(0).files[0]);
});
```